# Video processing library for java in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, video-streaming

I'm now looking for Java libraries for Video processing, I've read this post: 
[Video Processing Library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011397/video-processing-library-for-java) and then, tried some "hello world" tuts with Xuggle. But the problem is Xuggle use some Native Code, as said in their home page:

"Xuggler consists of a small amount of Java (i.e. architecture independent) code and a large amount of native code that needs to be specifically compiled for different operating systems. That means different binary packages must be used with different operating systems (unlike most Java programs)."

As we don't know much about which platforms used by Google, It's unlikely to use Xuggle.

So, can you please tell me some other solutions ?

Thanks.

Comment: I've been looking for something similar, for python. Get used to the idea you may have to roll your own!

Comment: That'll be a good idea if I have some solid video processing background :). In fact, I don't know much about this domain.

Comment: Perhaps check out Amazon cloud services, you have total control over the machine then and can run whatever software you like.

Comment: For some reasons, I cannot change the platform. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to do this on GAE. As you noted, Xuggle is a wrapper around native libraries which you can not use on GAE.

The other solution would be to use a IaaS provider, where you control the whole stack (OS and above). For example Amazon EC2 or other [VPS providers](http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/top-vps-providers/).

Comment: Is there any solution for GAE ? I can't change the platform :(

Comment: Then I'm afraid you've chosen the platform prior to deciding what your requirements are. If you have chosen this platform because it's free then you have to live within it's constraints. I'm considering farming work out to Amazon via GAE, plenty of people seem to do it in cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can now in 2016, using a [Google Cloud Managed VM](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/)